# How to use "where" in join to two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Main table:

(trip)

```
id | name
1  | USA
2  | Europe
3  | Asia
```

Childrens:

```
(plane)
id | trip_id | name | other
1  |    1    | aaa  |  w
2  |    1    | bbb  |  e
3  |    3    | ccc  |  rr

(boat)
id | trip_id | name
1  |    2    | jjj
2  |    2    | kkk
3  |    3    | lll
```

If I want to get trips with planes, then I can:

```
SELECT trip.* FROM trip INNER JOIN plane ON plane.trip_id = trip.id
```

If I want to get trips with boats, then I can:

```
SELECT trip.* FROM trip INNER JOIN boat ON boat.trip_id = trip.id
```

But how to get in one query all trips with planes or boats (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use **Left Join** like following

`select trip.*, isnull(plane.name, '-') as PlaneName,
isnull(boat.name, '-') as BoatName from trip 
left join plane ON plane.trip_id = trip.id
left JOIN boat ON boat.trip_id = trip.id`

It will return following table, feel free to use any field from any of these 3 tables...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT trip.* FROM trip INNER JOIN plane ON plane.trip_id = trip.id
UNION ALL
SELECT trip.* FROM trip INNER JOIN boat ON boat.trip_id = trip.id
```

Comment: Since the tables have a different number of columns, this query will not work, unless the common columns are explicitly defined or you add `NULL AS Other ` to the `boat` table.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve by `LEFT` join

```
SELECT trip.*,ifnull(plane.Name,'NA') as planetrip, ifnull(boat.Name,'NA')  boattrip FROM trip 
LEFT JOIN plane ON plane.trip_id = trip.id
LEFT JOIN boat ON boat.trip_id = trip.id
WHERE (plane.Name IS NOT NULL OR boat.Name IS NOT NULL)
```

SQL DEMO: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2ae5c/10

Comment: with this you would also get trips with no planes nor boats

Comment: @ vivoconunxino , I have added where clause to avoid such trips

Comment: yep, now it's ok  :p

Answer (score 2):

Try left joining the trips table to the other two tables.  The trick here is that we aggregate at the end by trip and detect if, for each trip, there was a match in the plane or boat tables.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(p.trip_id) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS has_plane,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(b.trip_id) > 0 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END AS has_boat
FROM trip t
LEFT JOIN plane p
    ON t.id = p.trip_id
LEFT JOIN boat b
    ON t.id = b.trip_id
GROUP BY t.id;

    id  name    has_plane   has_boat
1   1   USA     yes         no
2   2   Europe  no          yes
3   3   Asia    yes         yes
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the result on several rows you can use UNION 
but Your table plane and boat have not the same number of column so you should  use union with explict column name  eg:

```
  SELECT trip_id, plane.name, trip.name
  from plane
  inner join trip on trip.id = plane.trip_id
  UNION 
  SELECT trip_id, plane.name, trip.name
  from bout
  inner join trip on trip.id = boat.trip_id
```

or if you need  all values you must use a null column where needed

```
  SELECT trip_id, plane.name, trip.name, other
  from plane
  inner join trip on trip.id = plane.trip_id
  UNION 
  SELECT trip_id,plane.name, trip.name, null
  from bout
  inner join trip on trip.id = boat.trip_id
```